# SQL for XML namespace

Tags: sql, xml, xml-namespaces

Please help Me with thing.

I have 2 tables:

```
#head

PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
------ ------ ------
AAA    BBB    CCC

#body

NAME                 SEX                  EMAIL
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Tania                Female               mail@femail.com
Sergey               male                 mail@mail.com
```

To make XML I am using next query:

```
Query:

DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @xmlns VARCHAR(1000)

SET @xmlns = 'http://google.example'
SET @XML =

REPLACE(
            (
            SELECT TOP 1
            Param1 as 'Param1',
            Param2 as 'Param2',
            Param3 as 'Param3',
            @XMLNS AS  xmlns,

                (
                    SELECT 
                        NAME as 'NAME',
                        SEX as 'SEX',
                        EMAIL as 'EMAIL'
                    FROM 
                        #body AS BODY 
                    FOR XML PATH('BODY'),TYPE 
                ) 
                FROM 
                    #head AS HEAD
                FOR XML AUTO

            ),' xmlns=""',''
        ) 

SELECT CAST(@XML AS XML)  AS myXML
```

Current Result IS:

```
<HEAD xmlns="http://google.example" Param1="AAA" Param2="BBB" Param3="CCC">
  <BODY>
    <NAME>Tania</NAME>
    <SEX>Female</SEX>
    <EMAIL>mail@femail.com</EMAIL>
  </BODY>
  <BODY>
    <NAME>Sergey</NAME>
    <SEX>male</SEX>
    <EMAIL>mail@mail.com</EMAIL>
  </BODY>
</HEAD>
```

Expected Result Is:

```
<ns0:HEAD Param1="AAA" Param2="BBB" Param3="CCC" xmlns:ns0="http://google.example">
  <BODY>
    <NAME>Tania</NAME>
    <SEX>Female</SEX>
    <EMAIL>mail@femail.com</EMAIL>
  </BODY>
  <BODY>
    <NAME>Sergey</NAME>
    <SEX>male</SEX>
    <EMAIL>mail@mail.com</EMAIL>
  </BODY>
</ns0:HEAD>
```

Does anybody know how to reach expected Result ?

## Thanks in advance for any kind of help !

Comment: The tag "sql" is not enough! Please edit your question to tag the actual DBMS (vendor and version)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was SQL-Server (your code looks like this), you might try this:

```
create table #head(PARAM1 varchar(100), PARAM2 varchar(100), PARAM3 varchar(100));
insert into #head values
('AAA','BBB','CCC');

create table #body(NAME varchar(100), SEX  varchar(100), EMAIL varchar(100));
insert into #body values
 ('Tania','Female','mail@femail.com')
,('Sergey','male','mail@mail.com');
GO
```

--This will add namespaces to the BODY as well. Should not make problems, that's well known issue...

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://google.example' AS ns0)
SELECT PARAM1 AS [@Param1]
      ,PARAM2 AS [@Param2]
      ,PARAM3 AS [@Param3]
      ,(
        SELECT NAME,SEX,EMAIL
        FROM #body
        FOR XML PATH('BODY'),TYPE
       )
FROM #head
FOR XML PATH('ns0:HEAD');
```

--If you want to avoid inner namespaces, you could try this;

```
DECLARE @bodyXML XML=
(SELECT NAME,SEX,EMAIL
        FROM #body
        FOR XML PATH('BODY'),TYPE
);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://google.example' AS ns0)
SELECT PARAM1 AS [@Param1]
      ,PARAM2 AS [@Param2]
      ,PARAM3 AS [@Param3]
      ,@bodyXML
FROM #head
FOR XML PATH('ns0:HEAD');
```

--Clean-Up

```
GO
drop table #head;
drop table #body;
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP !